# Magento2, Admin panel. How to set ''require' for weight field to each sub-product of configuration product?

Tags: configurable-product, magento-2.2.1, product-weight

Magento CE 2.2.1: I need to force user to input the value for weight of each sub-product in configuration product while add new product.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set Weight attribute value to required true for force set weight to product at create time.

Go To Backend,
**Stores -> Configuration -> Attributes -> Product**
Find Weight attribute and edit weight attribute,
**Save Value Required to True from dropdown.**
[image]

Comment: After set 'yes' to attribute name 'weight' 
[Image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5PRe.png)

Comment: You have to set required field from product attributes.